# How can I create an Array in Descending Order?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm working on this project using Arrays. I have a method called createRandomIntArray that creates an array. This method is meant to return the Array in descending order. I have been able to do just that but I want to know if there is a more effective way to write this method than the way I wrote it. I have my code below.

```
    public static int[] createRandomIntArray(int n) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int[] result = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result[i] = random.nextInt(n);
        }
        Arrays.sort(result);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length / 2; i++) {
            int temp = result[i];
            result[i] = result[result.length - i - 1];
            result[result.length - i - 1] = temp;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `n` as upper bound for the random values in your first loop? If not one could rewrite the method to use `IntStream` instead of array internally.

Comment: n represents the size of the array. How many values should the array contain.

Comment: Ok currently by using `random.nextInt(n)` you’re using `n` as upper bound for the random values. This doesn’t make too much sense because of the sorting that is applied later on but at least no value will currently be bigger than `n`

Comment: This is how I was taught to do it by my professor. I just took what he did creating a random array and tried to get the array in descending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SortDes {  
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        int [] arr = new int [] {5, 2, 8, 7, 1};   
        int temp = 0;  
          
        System.out.println("Elements of original array: ");  
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");  
        }  
           
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {   
               if(arr[i] < arr[j]) {  
                   temp = arr[i];  
                   arr[i] = arr[j];  
                   arr[j] = temp;  
               }   
            }   
        }  
          
        System.out.println();  
          
        System.out.println("Elements of array sorted in descending order: ");  
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {   
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why use battle proven sorting algorithms if you can do it yourself in O(n^2)?

Comment: This works for me as a solution. Thank You.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @EzequielSoler The funny thing with this answer is that your initial solution in the question will perform better than this sort implementation. Arrays.sort will have O(nlogn) time complexity and your reversing code has O(n) (linear) complexity. This results in O(nlogn) complexity in total. Where this bubble sort implementation has O(n^2)

If O-Notation is of no meaning to you, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/50288253/4323935

Answer (score 5):

You could avoid reversing the sorted array by directly sorting reverse order:

```
Arrays.sort(result, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

As mentioned in the comments one could use `Random.ints(…)` if you’re not tied to using arrays:

```
random.ints(n, 0, n).boxed().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Comment: This is something I have never used before so I don't think my professor would want to see something like this done but thanks anyway for the response.

Comment: @EzequielSoler You're using `Arrays.sort` anyway, most professors would be thrilled to believe you read the javadocs to find out what options it can provide.

Comment: Yes but this is something that if I was asked how it worked it’s not something I can explain. I would rather write code that I understand instead of taking the shortcut and take code that works but I have no understanding of it.

Answer (score 2):

Using Java Streams

```
private static int[] createRandomIntArray(int n) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints()   // Stream of random ints
        .limit(n)                               // Limit the stream to n values
        .boxed()                                // Convert to Stream of Integer Objects for reverse sorting
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())     // Sort in reverse Order
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)            // Map back to primitive ints
        .toArray();                             // as Array
}
```

Comment: This is something I have never used before so I don't think my professor would want to see something like this done but thanks anyway for the response.

Comment: No problem. I suggest looking into Java Stream API. It makes code more compact. Doing the sort manually like in your accepted answer is extremelly inefficient, because it runs with O(n²) performance. Java applies mutiple sort strategies based on the number of elements to be as efficient as possible. You could do as dpr suggested the Arrays.sort as you already did but with the reverse order Comparator.

I'll add comments to my code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Here's a gist comparing Java sorting vs manual storting implementation from your accepted answer -> https://gist.github.com/amalic/1afa0bdfa4220ae0a6c319467969e1cf

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative which is using `Stream`.

```
Arrays.stream(result).sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: This is something I have never used before so I don't think my professor would want to see something like this done but thanks anyway for the response.